# Rim brakes causing vibration and 'honking' noise, like a flock of angry geese

Tags: brakes

I've recently acquired a new set of (aluminium) wheels, and at first they were fine, but now when I brake the rear lightly I can feel a shuddering/vibration through the bike. If I press the brake harder, 9/10 times, it will make a loud honking noise, which kind of sounds like an angry goose (i.e. it is not a squealing noise) These are rim brakes btw, as most threads I've searched are a similar problem but are with disc brakes, not rim brakes.

What I did was:

- Took pads out, cleaned them.
- Aligned shoes to braking surface
- Used a business card to toe in the brakes.

This seemed to stop it for a few rides, but the noise has come back again. Any ideas on what could be causing this? I am also using the correct pads as recommended by the wheel manufacturer (Shamal Mille, with Campy blue pads).

Note: An example of the noise can be found here:

Comment: You probably need more toe-in than a business card would provide.

Comment: The business card was folded to provide enough thickness. The pads seem toed in enough (visually). The problem is also different to squealing brakes (which I've had in the past). This is a really loud "honking" noise, like an air horn or an angry goose.

Comment: On one of my bikes the squeal is much lower in pitch and louder than any other bike I've ridden. It's much better with good pads (koolstop Eagle 2 dual compound) but still gets bad at times ( it's good when people step out in front of me) . This bike has chrome rims. If the noise stops and starts with constant pressure on the brakes I suspect the wheel needs truing. Check that both pads touch the rim at the same time/pressure all the way round.

Comment: As stated, this is not a duplicate of the brake squealing question, it is not a squealing noise, it is a loud honking noise. I was able to find the answer here (which is a video of the actual noise): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2Dgd1Q2hFs

The issue was there was TOO MUCH toe in. I reduced the toe so the pads were almost parallel to the rim and the noise is gone.

Comment: Stupid question:  Are you sure you toed in the pads in the right direction?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. I toed them in so that the front end of the pad hits the rim first, is this correct?